# programmatically clicking combo-box button in swt

Tags: java, swt

How to cause the click/ selection event in SWT through code ? without the user actually clicking the control, the event should be fired !! is it possible?

I need to automate the clicking of a combo box button and the dropping down of the list and the selection of the item - as done by the user!! i.e., playback of the recorded events. Which listener do i need to use ? i tried selection but couldn't get the results.

```
combo.setText(combo.getItem(combo.getSelectionIndex()));
```

Comment: What have you tried? Edit your Q and post your code. Please also read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate a selection event with something like:

```
Event event = new Event();

event.widget = combo;
event.type = SWT.Selection;

combo.getDisplay().post(event);
```

You might need to set other fields in `Event`

Comment: Thank you greg-449 !! The code works fine but the combo is not updated with the changes, the event is fired but the selection is not reflected. Also the drop down of the combo list is not happening on the clicking of the combo button. Any suggestion for that?

Comment: This code just fires the event to the listeners, nothing else. You can use `setText` or `setSelection` to update the combo. I don't think there is a way to make the drop down appear.

Comment: Thank you @greg-449 !! 

also,
display.addFilter(SWT.Selection,new Listener()
        {
  public void handleEvent(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event e) {

// code to be implemented
}
});

and then 

widget.notifyListeners(SWT.Selection, new Event());      does a similar job. Just wanted to confirm about the dropdown !!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate the user interactions for testing purpose, try windowstester. It also has recording feature where you can record the ui activities and just run it over the test...

https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/download-wintester

Comment: Thank you @Karthik Rocky , I'd gone through wintester but it has many features that aren't useful for my testing. So I'm more interested in a customised plug-in !!